# Should “round” only be used to describe 2-d objects?

Tags: word-usage

My high school teacher used to say, "No, the world is not *round* it is *globular*". Strictly speaking, is *round* more appropriately used to describe 2-dimensional objects (circle, oval, tire, plate or saucer) and globular, spherical or even cylindrical better for 3-dimensional objects (ball, egg, tube, pint glass or the earth). Or are we just dealing with a persnickety high school teacher?

Comment: Sounds like pedantry to me. When saying a table has 'rounded corners', for example, no-one seriously thinks of the table's third dimension (height) as being remotely relevant to the statement.

Comment: If you want to be picky, the Earth is an oblate spheroid. You can also ask them what a 4dimensional round object would be called !

Comment: @Martin: a 4-dimensional round object is apparently called a *3-sphere* or *glome*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere

Comment: So, if you don't believe the earth is an *oblate spheroid* but still imagine it as a plate with water falling off the edges, you could still say the world is *round*...? I think my head's imploding. >_<

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Persnickety. Round is commonly used to describe spherical objects:

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/round

> 2 . Spherical; shaped like a ball; having a circular cross-section in more than one direction.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/round

> 19 . any round shape, as a circle, ring or sphere.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/round

> 1 . a. Being such that every part of the surface or the circumference is equidistant from the center: a round ball.

Comment: +1: to me "round" is a more vague word than "circular" so using it for a sphere or a slightly non-spherical spheroid etc is fine unless the context is geometry or something else very technical.

Answer (score 6):

Merriam-Webster [defines *round*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/round?show=0&t=1305747173) as:

> having every part of the surface or circumference equidistant from the center

It sounds to me like a sphere would fit that definition nicely.

It's possible that math or geometry specialists might define *round* as only applying to two-dimensional objects, but that usage would be properly considered jargon, rather than common English.

Answer (score 0):

1 the earth is not round,  A circle is round(1d), a ball is round or spheric(2d). The earth is flatten at the poles sow  round or spheric do not fully describe that shape